# How to create a human readable normalized string?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, normalize

I need to replace special characters like

- ü -> ue
- ä -> ae
- é -> e

in a string. what is the best way to do it?

Comment: You should fix your backend code so that it can handle special characters.

Comment: If you're somehow unable to follow SLaks excelent suggestion, you must first formulate what is a "special" (or "normal") character to you and what you want to replace them with.

Comment: most of our app is on the client... talking back to the server to get a normalized string takes to long and is overkill no?

Comment: Please change the question to include the 'human-readable' requirement, and elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2):

After googling i couldn't find anything suitable. So i ended up writing my own.

```
normalize = (s) ->

  mapping = 
    'ä': 'ae'
    'ö': 'oe'
    'ü': 'ue'
    '&': 'and'
    'é': 'e'
    'ë': 'e'
    'ï': 'i'
    'è': 'e'
    'à': 'a'
    'ù': 'u'
    'ç': 'c'
    "'": ''
    '´': ''

  r = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapping).join('|'), 'g')
  s.replace(r, (s)->
    mapping[s]
  )
```

Comment: Char-by-char loops in JS awfully slow. Better solution is to automatically construct regexp that covers all keys from mapping and replace with values using function as argument for `String.replace`.

Comment: Yep. Good thing that you have to initialize r only once!

Comment: Is that a complete list of all the characters you want to replace?

Comment: this won't replace the uppercase characters .. like Ü Ä Ö

Answer (score 2):

Consider [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) (and the associated decode).

The example given on that w3schools page:

```
var uri="http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
```

document.write(encodeURIComponent(uri));

Output:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab
```

Note the å in the middle becomes `%C3%A5`.

If you don't mind `* @ - _ + . /` not being encoded, there is also [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) (and unescape()).

EDIT in light of 'human-readable' requirement:

Be careful that you cover all the characters that might come up by doing an 'oe' type replacement, and that you never attempt to convert these 'readable' strings back to their original form, or you will corrupt things in the transformation. This is the point of the escape and unescape methods.

Consider applying escape/unescape after your own transform to catch any remaining unexpected characters.

Comment: i thought about it but we need something human readable... maybe i should have called the function humanNurmalize :)